# Windows 10 Iot core and Arduino

Tags: arduino, windows-iot

I am a newbie in raspberry pi. can you help me? thanks. Is raspberry pi with Windows IoT core OS can connect or communicate to Arduino, like uploading sketch or control it using visual studio community? thanks guys.

Comment: Which Raspberry Pi do you have? If it's a 3B+, 3A+, 4B1GB, 4B2GB or 4B4GB then you can't boot Win10 IoT on it. Switch to Raspbian Linux and working with Arduinos becomes trivial.

Comment: It was raspberry pi 3 b

Comment: I installed windows 10 IoT core on rpi but I'm not sure how to connect arduino uno or mega to it :(

Comment: Try asking the same question on https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/home?forum=WindowsIoT